# How to enable websocket in ecs?

Tags: websocket, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using in my application developed in nest websocket to allow a communication of a service that is controlled by a timer while the user performs various actions.

I have my app deployed in ecs using the balancer and its corresponding listener for operation according to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/using-websockets-and-load-balancers-part-two/)

Working with websockets works locally, but when deploying in aws, the websocket call fails.

What I currently have:

ECS, LB, LISTENER, A CNAME RECORD IN ROUTE53 WITH THE NAME OF MY API URL test-myapp-backend.mydomain.com and the value corresponding to the load balancer, my api url has a success result when doing the called, but when making the request for the websocket it fails.

```
io.connect("https://test-myapp-backend.mydomain.com/register-activity", {
        transports: ["websocket"],
        auth: {
          token: userToken,
        },
      }),
```

I have 2 cname records, one for the api call with http and another for the same balancer but with wss

CNAME

```
test-myapp-backend.mydomain.com = balancerdns

test-myapp-backend.mydomain.com = wss://balancerdns
```

Comment: `test-myapp-backend.mydomain.com = wss://balancerdns` is an invalid CNAME record. You don't put protocols (`ws://`) in a CNAME record. CNAME records just point a domain name to a server.

Comment: "when deploying in aws, the websocket call fails" It would be extremely helpful to see what the actual failure is. Is it a timeout, or some sort of error? Please edit your question to include the exact error details.

Comment: I found the solution, the url for the websocket generates this endpoint /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket, so it was necessary to add this path to the rules of the listener in this way /socket.io/*  thank u

Comment: A key piece of information would have been that you had more than one rule configured on your load balancer.